# Find n occurrences from group of characters

Tags: regex, perl

Given a string, I am suppose to print "two" if i find exactly two characters from the group `xyz`.

Given `jxyl` print two

Given `jxyzl` print nothing

Given `jxxl` print two

I am very new to perl so this is my approach.

```
my $word = "jxyl";
@char = split //, $word;
my $size = $#char;

for ( $i = 0; $i < $size - 1; $i++ ) {
    if ( $char[i] eq "x" || $char[i] eq "y" || $char eq "z" ) {
        print "two";
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is isn't working correctly?

Comment: would `xx` qualify, or do the characters have to be different?

Comment: xx would also print two

Comment: @Alnitak good point i should edit my question and mention that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the FAQ:

`perldoc -q count`

[How can I count the number of occurrences of a substring within a string?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string?)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $count = () = $_ =~ /[xyz]/g;
    print "$_ two\n" if $count == 2;
}    

__DATA__
jxyl
jxyzl
jxxl
```

Outputs:

```
jxyl two
jxxl two
```

Answer (score 4):

You basically want to count the number of specific characters in a string.

You can use [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $count = $_ =~ tr/xyz//;
    print "$_ - $count\n";
}

__DATA__
jxyl
jxyzl
jxxl
```

Outputs:

```
jxyl - 2
jxyzl - 3
jxxl - 2
```

Determining if there are exactly 2 can be done after the counting.

Comment: `tr` works on `$_` by default, and if you leave the RHS empty nothing is replaced, so you can simply say `my $count = tr/xyz//;` (although leaving `$_` is probably clearer for beginners).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, I was being more explicit because of OP's stated 2 hours of experience.  I wasn't sure how to non-destructively search, so I added an explicit RHS.  I've simplified that now based off your advice though.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the best way to do it, but here is a regex for fun and to show there is more than one way to do things.

```
perl -e'$word = "jxyl"; print "two" if $word =~ /^[^xyz]*[xyz][^xyz]*[xyz][^xyz]*$/'
```